# Salesforce Connect - Associated table in the external data source can't be found

Tags: json, webservices, odata, salesforce-connect

New to Salesforce Connect, but not necessarily new to parsing JSON responses and utilizing webservices.

I am attempting a test connection to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments with Salesforce Connect.

When utilizing ODATA 2.0 or 4.0 with type set to JSON and no authentication set, I receive the following error after clicking Validate and Sync:

> This data isn't available because the associated table in the external
>   data source can't be found. Contact your administrator for help.
>   Attempted query URL:
>   https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/$metadata

When utilizing Simple Url I receive the following error after clicking Validate and Sync:

> Simpleurl type external data sources do not support authentication

Why is Salesforce Connect auto-appending the $metadata to the call?

How do I need to configure Salesforce Connect to utilize an endpoint like this so that is translates into external objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the OData model is a *protocol*; it expects to be able to call sub-resources of the specified URL and get specific responses back. For example, $metadata returns a list of objects/fields available in the resource. There's examples of doing this [on this trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning_connect/lightning_connect_integrate). OData doesn't work on static files, unless you have all the files in a specific format.

Your best option would be a [custom adapter](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=apex_add_external_data_source.htm&type=5). In this method, you specify Apex code to parse the resource (in your case, JSON), and this in turn allows you to use static files like you expect. There's quite a bit of text to read, which I won't replicate here, but you can also [start here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connector_custom_adapter.htm) in the documentation and walk through the sample code and definitions.

Comment: Thanks, 

This set me straight, I initially received a completely incorrect explanation of ODATA.